# PowerShell Script or Typescript for hiding default WebParts from a modern team site

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, sharepoint-online

I need a way (powershell script or typescript code) to hide from a modern team site all default webparts (text, image, twitter... ).

I know that I need to set the attribute "hiddenFromToolbox": true but I don't know how to get all the default webparts from the page and set this attribute to them.

Comment: Many will tell you here, this is not a script writing service and the folks here, as a rule will not write scripts from scratch for you. The folks here will help you with a script you are having issues with, but you need to post that code and the error(s) you are having, and what you are expecting as a result.

Answer (score 0):

The behavior is not really supported or recommended at the moment:  https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/issues/1674

[image]